# Creating dynamic methods inside classes

Tags: php, oop

I want to create methods at runtime and add them to the class. Ok, let me explain the context of it.

I have an array of strings. Based on this array, i want to create methods with different functionalities depending on that string, for example.

```
$fruits = ["apple", "pear", "avocado"];
foreach($fruits as $fruit){
  if($fruit == "apple"){
    // create function doing X
  }else{
        // create function doing Y
   }
}
```

Php has the method `create_function()` but it creates an annonymous function, which i'm not interested on. I want to be able to invoke like, `MyClass->apple()`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has no such function called `create_method()`, you might be thinking of [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create-function). However, PHP classes do have a magic method that allows you invoke function calls on inaccessible methods called [`__call()`](http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading#object.call) for objects and there is also [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading#object.callstatic) for static class methods.

> `__call()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.
>
> `__callStatic()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

But it's important to distinguish the concept of dynamically adding methods at runtime from the idea of dynamically creating code at runtime. The concept of registering callbacks, for example is usually a sound one using closures, for example.

```
class Fruits {

    protected $methods = [];

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (isset($this->methods[$name])) {
            $closure = $this->methods[$name];
            return $closure(...$arguments);
        }
    }

    public function registerMethod($name, Callable $method) {
        $this->methods[$name] = $method;
    }

}

$apple = function($color) {
    return "The apple is $color.";
};

$pear = function($color) {
    return "The pear is $color.";
};

$avocado = function($color) {
    return "The avocado is $color.";
};

$methods = ["apple" => $apple, "pear" => $pear, "avocado" => $avocado];

$fruits = new Fruits;

foreach($methods as $methodName => $method) {
    $fruits->registerMethod($methodName, $method);
}

echo $fruits->apple("red"), "\n";
echo $fruits->pear("green"), "\n";
echo $fruits->avocado("green"), "\n";
```

Output

```
The apple is red.
The pear is green.
The avocado is green.
```

Comment: my bad, i miss type the create_method. Sorry

Comment: Using this approach, the definition of the function have to be done using a kwown array size and values or not?.

Comment: No, PHP arrays are dynamically sized.

Comment: I mean, using the approach you proposed, manually creating each method under the class definition and assigning each array value to the function reference.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The example demonstrates how to dynamically register anonymous methods to the object. You could implement that however you want. Though, once again, heed extreme caution in conflating the concept of dynamically adding methods to an instance from the concept of dynamically generating code at runtime.